# What is the complexity of the CUBE operator in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, complexity-theory, data-warehouse

What is the complexity *(Big O notation)* of a `CUBE` operation in SQL (Microsoft) or Oracle?

e.g.

```
SELECT x1, x2, SUM(x3)
FROM xyz
GROUP BY CUBE (x1, x2)
```

Comment: That can't be answered with the information given.  It depends on the indexing on the table, the database version being used, whether it will spill out of memory to page files, amount of concurrent processes, etc, etc, etc, etc, etc...

Comment: I understand @MatBailie - What about the worst case complexity? So assuming no indexing, etc. As `CUBE` can be rewritten to multiple `SELECT` statements, how complex (how many) would that be for `CUBE (x1, ..., xn)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity is:

```
2^c * n log(n)
```

where:

```
c = number of columns in the cube
n = number of rows in the table
```

The `2^c` is for *all combinations of the columns*.  `n log(n)` is for the aggregation operator -- which is generally equivalent to a sort in the absence of an index.

Because `c` is never really that big -- for instance, 10 would generate a lot of rows -- we could treat it as a constant (in that case 1,000,000) and say the operation is essentially `n log(n)`.